# Electronic dice is "rigged", roll affected by the previous one. Long term estimation

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose an electronic dice is "rigged" so that on every roll there is a 1/5 chance to roll the roll as the previous one. The rest of the rolls have equal probability of appearing.
If the first roll was a 2, what is the long term probability that the nth roll will be also 2?

Comment: Hint:  The probability that the $n^{th}$ toss is a $2$, $p_n$ can be derived from $p_{n-1}$ and the given conditions.  Now use the assumption that, in the limit, $p_{n-1}=p_n$.

Comment: Can't see it. I can't understand how to incorporate the fact that for a random 3 the chance to get a 3 is different than anything else. And how that affects coming back to 2

Comment: There are two paths to getting a $2$ on toss $n$.  Either you got a $2$ on toss $n-1$ and then you threw another $2$, or you got a non-$2$ on toss $n-1$ and then you threw a $2$.

Comment: True, but it is more likely that I will have a 2 on the n-1 throw since I start with 2! So how does this affect?

Comment: The assumption is that $p_{n-1}=p_n$ for large $n$.  Of course, one can prove that this is true but here, since they speak of "the long term probability" I expect you are meant to simply assume this.

Comment: If I assume this I am done! I was hoping to divide the previous throws on n and n-m and somehow incorporate that

Comment: So you know the answer to the question?  At least under the assumption that the limit exists?  Please edit your post to include that.

Comment: If you want to prove that the limit exists, establish the recursion between $p_n$ and $p_{n-1}$.  Solve that recursion and take the limit as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Well at least I think I know this to be true. I have some knowledge gaps and hoped to understand this.

Comment: My last comment gives the road map to proving that the limit exists.  Just go step by step.  Start by writing down the recursion.